# Azure Active Directory self service sign up with any email and password

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to set up a self service account creation / sign up in a web app and I want to use Azure Active Directory for the backend due to all the features and integration it provides. As far as I can tell from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow) it is possible to have Google and Facebook integrations for ex, however I also want to have the option for new users to just register with any email, regardless of domain. When I try the self service sign up with a non MS email I get an error like this:

[image]

Was hoping to solve this caveat with the [one time passcode authentication via email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/one-time-passcode) feature, this somewhat works in the sense that the user receives a OTP on the email and they can enter the webapp, however they have to do this each time. I see the user has been created as a guest in the Azure AD, however there is no direct way for the user to set a password and just login via email/password, it has to go through the OTP generation each time which is very cumbersome.

Is there a way to have an email/password self service sign up with Azure AD for any email domain?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add the Custom Domain Name in Azure AD, i.e. the domain from which your user will sign-in. You can add up to 5000 managed domain names.

You can keep the Primary domain as the main firm's domain and any other domain as a custom one

If the domain is already added then your user will be able to do a self-service sign-in

The article will help you on how you can add custom domain to your Azure AD tenant:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-manage

Comment: i think there is a misunderstanding here regarding the word "custom", i edited the question with "any". Your answer implies I actually control those custom domains, whereas I actually want to be able for user with any email or domain to be able to register with an email/pass on the webapp.